# Laravel. Reglas para inserción

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Quiero implementar una funcionalidad en mi API, aunque la verdad no sé muy bien como desarrollarla, explico un poco mi idea:

Quiero "validar" o codificar unas "reglas" para que no puedan hacer solicitudes por doquier, la cosa sería que cuando un usuario haga una solicitud de a mi API, la API sea capaz de comprobar si esa solicitud es procedente, entonces, requeriría de verificar 3 campos, uno, el id de departamento asociado al usuario, y 2 las fechas a solicitar. Entonces tendría 3 campos, `area_id`, `date_from`, `date_to` que necesito comprobar si algún usuario del mismo área tiene esas fechas cogidas.La cosa es que no sé muy bien cómo empezar a desarrollarlo porque tengo el método `store` con el que la solicitud se procesa y guarda en la base de datos, este es el método:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'worker_id' => 'required',
        'type' => 'required',
        'observations' => 'required',
        'datefilter' => 'required',
        'area_id' => 'required',
    ]);

    $vacation = new Vacation();
    $vacation -> worker_id = $request['worker_id'];
    $vacation -> type = $request['type'];
    $vacation -> observations = $request['observations'];
    $vacation -> area_id = $request['area_id'];

    $vacation -> date_from = date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom));
    $vacation -> date_to = date("y-m-d", strtotime( $dateTo ));

    //comprobar aqui
    $vacation->save();



    return redirect('/home');
}
```

Justo antes del `save()` tendría que comprobar si otro usuario del mismo departamento tiene esas fechas ya guardadas en alguna solicitud hecha previamente. Mi duda es: ¿Dónde codifico eso? ¿En el propio método? ¿Tengo que hacer algo a través de la vista? ¿Cómo le devuelvo un mensaje al usuario desde el método para decirle que existe algún error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He aqui el resultado de sus sugerencias, no se si sera la manera mas eficiente, pero si la que me funciono.

```
$dep =\DB::table('workers')->select('workers.area_id')
        ->where(['workers.id' => $request->worker_id])
        ->get(); 

    $vacation = new Vacation();
    $vacation -> area_id = $dep[0]->area_id;
    //parse dates
    $date  = explode('-',$request['datefilter']);
    $dateFrom = date("y-m-d",strtotime( $date[0]));
    $dateTo = date("y-m-d",strtotime($date[1]));

    $vacation -> date_from = date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom));
    $vacation -> date_to = date("y-m-d", strtotime( $dateTo ));

    $guardadas = \DB::table('vacations')
        ->where('date_from',  $dateFrom)
        ->where('date_to',  $dateTo)
        ->where('area_id',  $dep[0]->area_id )
        ->get();

    if(!$guardadas){
       $vacation->save();
```

Realmente no necesitaba parsear la fecha, ya que la parseo al meter los datos al objeto. 
Gracias por sus aportaciones, no lo habría conseguido sin ustedes.

Answer (score 4):

Puedes utilizar el método `exists()` para comprobar si existe ya algún modelo:

```
$vacaciones = Vacation::whereAreaId($request->area_id)
                  ->whereDateFrom(date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom)))
                  ->whereDateTo(date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateTo)))
                  ->exists();
```

Una nota, para el manejo de fechas en Laravel no es necesario usar `date()` y casi que tampoco `strtotime()`, Carbon (ya incluido en Laravel) te ofrece las herramientas para hacer practicamente todas las operaciones que necesites con fechas.

También podrías hacer cierta validación (Dependiendo de la lógica de tu aplicación) con `firstOrCreate()` o con `firstOrNew()`

Comment: Muchas gracias Shaz por tu pronta respuesta,  la verdad, uso el strtotime, porque saco la fecha de un datepicker que me da las dos fechas juntas y necesito parsearlas para insertarlas en la base de datos si no no las inserta, investigare sobre carbon a ver si puedo hacer esto de una manera mas automática y probare la sugerencia que me has dicho.

Comment: No entiendo por qué la otra respuesta es mejor que esta, en la otra están haciendo un query innecesario que tardará más tiempo en ejecutarse.

Comment: Porque no me deja marcar dos respuestas como validas, ni tu solución me sirvio al 100%, ni la del, pero entre todo saque la solución.

Comment: Entonces agrega tu propia respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Antes de insertar mediante BD Query de Laravel, comprueba si existe algún registro en la base de datos

```
//Nombre de la tabla he puesto vacaciones
$vacacionesCogidas= DB::table('vacaciones')
    ->where('date_from',  date("y-m-d", strtotime($dateFrom)))
    ->where('date_to',  date("y-m-d", strtotime( $dateTo )))
    ->get();
if(!$vacacionesCogidas){
   $vacation->save();
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu aportación, justo me faltaba la condición. Saludos!